# Select one line, one line above and one line below

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table with a value column. I need to select the line chosen by the user (on the front), one line above and one line below, so:

My 'orders' table rows

```
----------------------------------------------
id   |   price |
----------------------------------------------
1    |  1500.00 | 
2    |  1380.00 |
3    |  1880.00 |
4    |  1900.00 |
5    |  1450.00 |
6    |  1700.00 |
```

If the person chose: 1450.00, I want to bring **1450.00**, **1380.00** and **1500.00**. Is it possible to make this MySql select? or will i have to do this in php?

I only have the initial query for now:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`
ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: Only these 3? 1450.00, 1380.00 and 1500.00

Comment: `WHERE price = 1450.00 OR price < 1450.00 OR price > 1450.00 LIMIT 3` Maybe, maybe not...

Comment: Yep!, Only 3 not exactly 'these' 3 values, but always 3 values, the one selected, one above and one below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select max and min price to get row. Let try this code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders A
WHERE A.price = 1450.00
OR A.price = (SELECT MAX(B.price) FROM orders B WHERE B.price < 1450.00)
OR A.price = (SELECT MIN(B.price) FROM orders B WHERE B.price > 1450.00)
```

Comment: Yes man, this is working perfectly as I expected, the three lines were selected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is using 2 MySQL statements. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `price`>=$user_price ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT 2
```

Which should give you the user's selected price and the row above. Then you can execute

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `price`<$user_price ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which should give you the row below.

I'm not sure if there's a way to combine the two queries, but if I do find anything I'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get this, use `max() on < 1450` and and `min() on > 1450`

```
select * from test
where price in 
    (select price from test where price = 1450)
        or price in
            (select max(price) from test where price < 1450)
            or price in
                (select min(price) from test where price > 1450)
```

instead of using `or`, use `in` instead to more cleaner.

```
select * from test
where price in (1450, 
   (select max(price) from test where price < 1450),           
         (select min(price) from test where price > 1450))
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=rriMaMnGdg)

Comment: should it be `select max(price) from test where price < 1450`?

Comment: @catcon, yes, your right.

Answer (score 0):

If the prices are unique and you want exactly three rows:

```
(select o.*
 from orders o
 where o.price <= :price
 order by o.price
 limit 2
) union all
(select o.*
 from orders o
 where o.price > :price
 order by o.price desc
 limit 1
);
```

Your question does not clarify what to do in these cases:

- When the price is less than or equal to the minimum price.
- When the price is greater than or equal to the maximum price.
- When there are duplicate prices.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should work

```sql
select price 
    from orders
    where price <= (select min(price) from orders where price > 1450.00)
order by price desc
limit 3
```